# Установка пакетов языка go на windows

Tags: windows, golang

Задам, скорее всего, довольно тупой вопрос.
Как установить пакеты с github или golang для языка go на windows через консоль?
Знаю, что на ликунсе это через get <ссылка> делается, а как на винде?

Answer (score 0):

для `go` пакеты ставляться так `go get <package_name>`
Но нужно убедится что go записан в системную переменную `PATH`

Всё есть в доке https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies

Comment: Я пробовал так, у меня возникает следующая ошибка:

go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package golang.org/x/net/html: exec: "git": executable file not found in %PATH%

Понимаю, что проблема, скорее всего, с переменными среды, но я не смог разобраться, в чем именно

Comment: вот https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH#windows

Comment: Да я вроде бы все сделал правильно. У меня есть переменная GOPATH с адресом C:\gopath и в переменную PATH я добавил %GOPATH%\bin. Но у меня все равно вылезает та же ошибка в консоли.

Comment: Консоль перезапускали?

Comment: перезапускал, ничего не поменялось

Comment: а `go version` работает?

Comment: Все, кажется, я решил проблему, нужно было перейти по ссылке из ошибки (golang.org/x/net/html) и скачать git, после этого все заработало